# Import an existing Navbar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

So I've been working on an existing REACT project, without any prior knowledge of react. I have a .js file which holds all the links, and I somehow need to call to this file and have those links shown in the navbar I'm working with. [the .js data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wUjs.png) If anyone knows how I would call to this in my .jsx file and have those links shown in the navbar which is in the .jsx file id really appreciate it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what is the MenuData file call? I'm assuming MenuData.js. You have to know the relative locations of MenuData.js and the parent file.

If they are in the same directory, you import it in like this:

```
import MenuData from './MenuData';
```

If they are in the parent directory, you have to import like this:

```
import MenuData from '../MenuData';
```

Or something like this if it's in another directory:

```
import MenuData from '../Parent/MenuData';
```

Just Google how to import React files if you're confused.

Once you import it correctly, you can use it like this:

```
MenuData[0].label //'Overview'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Gonna try this out right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to import your navbar component respecting the filepath as mentioned in the previous answer, and then to have it displayed, you need it to add it in the component into which you imported it:

```
return (
<Navbar />
<SomeComponent />
...
<Footer />
```